# Is nginx-extras supposed to have passenger compiled with it?

Tags: ppa, nginx

From the way [the Launchpad description reads](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/nginx-extras), the `nginx-extras` package should have the Passenger module installed with it.

However, when I install `nginx-extras` and try to enable Passenger, I get the "unknown directive 'passenger_root'" error that indicates the module is not installed.

Is this package intended to have the Passenger module with it, or am I misreading the Launchpad description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find passenger in the description for quantal (given in your link) and nowhere else (checked saucy, wheezy, sid). I also tried and can't get it to work with these packages (getting the same error message with `nginx -t`).

However, I would like to mention there is a solution [installing NGINX with Phusion Passenger](http://wiki.brightbox.co.uk/docs%3aphusion-passenger) using the [Brightbox PPA](https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/passenger-nginx).
This works fine for me in precise (12.04 LTS).

Comment: Yeah, it seems they've changed the docs since I posted that, and I ended up either using Brightbox or doing my own build (since I needed modules that the Brightbox PPA didn't come with standard).